# NameError: name 'mode' is not defined

Tags: pandas, numpy

Bonjour,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

df is:

```
    month   year    sale    name
0   1   2012    55  A
1   4   2014    40  B
2   7   2013    84  C
3   10  2014    31  d
```

code is:

```
agg_func_text = {'name': [ 'nunique', mode, set]}
df.groupby(['year']).agg(agg_func_text)
```

That produces:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [66], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 agg_func_text = {'name': [ 'nunique', mode, set]}
      2 df.groupby(['year']).agg(agg_func_text)
```

NameError: name 'mode' is not defined

Something is wrong but what?

Regards,
Atapalou

Answer (score 1):

`mode` is Series method; `groupby` objects don't have it. You have to specify that `Series.mode` is the one you want to call.

```
agg_func_text = {'name': [ 'nunique', pd.Series.mode, set]}
out = df.groupby(['year']).agg(agg_func_text)
```

Output:

```
        name                
     nunique    mode     set
year                        
2012       1       A     {A}
2013       1       C     {C}
2014       2  [B, d]  {B, d}
```

Comment: from scipy.stats import skew, mode That works. Why?

Comment: @Atapalou that's because you're importing them from the module, so `mode` or `skew` is defined.